# Returning To Default Mode Using Island Grammar Without Consuming Token

Tags: antlr

I'm still trying to parse a simple Javadoc style format using ANTLR. Basically the format looks like this:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @name someId
 */
```

My parser grammar is here:

```
query_doc       :   BEGIN_QDOC description name NOMANSLAND* END_QDOC;

description     :   (DESCRIPTION_TEXT | NOMANSLAND)*;

name            :   OPEN_NAME INNER_WS NAMEID INNER_WS* CLOSE_NAME;
```

My lexer grammar is here:

```
BEGIN_QDOC          :   '/**';


END_QDOC            :   ('*/');


NOMANSLAND          :   '\r'? '\n' (' ' | '\t')* '*' (' ' | '\t')*;


DESCRIPTION_TEXT    :   ~('\n');


OPEN_NAME                   :   '@name' -> mode(NAME);

mode NAME;


INNER_WS                    :   (' ' | '\t')+;


NAMEID                      :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_' | '?')+;

CLOSE_NAME                  :   (('\r'? '\n') | '*/')  -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

This appears to be working okay for the most part except for closing the @name definition in the following case:

```
/**
 * @name someId*/
```

The above should be perfectly valid. We should not need a new line before ending the comment with '*/'. The issue I am having is that '*/' terminates the name definition successfully, but it consumes the token and only returns to the default mode so I need to have:

```
/**
 * @name someId*/*/
```

if I actually want it to end the comment. I want it to return to the default mode and then realize that this token should end the comment (i.e. it should match END_QDOC). How can I accomplish this in ANTLR? I tried fixing it so that CLOSE_NAME is the inverse of ID:

```
CLOSE_NAME : ~('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_' | '?');
```

But ANTLR still consumes the * leaving a unrecognized token error on the remaining '/'. What I would really like to do is have ANTLR exit the mode without consuming the token so that '*/' is the next token when we return to DEFAULT_MODE. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rather than use the `mode` command, you probably want to use `-> pushMode(NAME)` and `-> popMode` to go back to the default mode.

For your `CLOSE_NAME` rule, you could use a predicate instead of a matching literal for handling the end of a comment:

```
CLOSE_NAME
  : ( '\r'? '\n'
    | {_input.LA(1) == '*' && _input.LA(2) == '/'}?
    )
    -> popMode
  ;
```

This can produce a zero-length token and wasn't allowed in ANTLR 4.0, but the restriction was removed (changed to a warning) in ANTLR 4.1 since we realized that a zero-length token could be used to trigger a mode change and thus avoid infinite loops.

Comment: I must be missing something because that didn't work. Now the token just disappears. It doesn't show up as part of CLOSE_NAME, but I'm still getting mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting CLOSE_NAME

Comment: SO does IntStream.LA actually consume the char? That's not clear from the documentation. If LA stands for look ahead then that's what I want but it doesn't appear to be working properly.